# Where to use would?

Tags: american-english

I have a lot of problems with the use of "would", I don't know where it should be used, but I know that it has so many indications.

Can someone explain me why this sentence is structured like this?

> Because of you I **knew** this, otherwise, I **would have** no idea.

Comment: Because "explain me something" is not grammatical in English, you should probably visit our sister site for [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/would) lists seven different ways of using 'would'.  One of them is a conditional mood, which describes the outcome of an imagined event or situation.  They give this example of conditional mood:

> He would lose his job if he were identified.

Your example is also conditional, because you're imagining that you wouldn't know whatever it is you know if it wasn't for this person.  You could restructure your example like this:

> I would have no idea if you hadn't told me.

Comment: You're not citing the OED (which is at OED.com) but rather Lexico or NOAD (or maybe they reprinted it elsewhere).

Comment: Why you used the past perfect with the verb "Tell", I think you should use past simple like in the example above